# If n > 1 is a composite number, then $\sigma(n) > n+\sqrt{n} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum

I know $\sigma(n)$ might greater than $n$, but why $\sqrt{n}$ related in this problem? Anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: "stuck this problem" - what exactly is the problem???

Comment: If $d$ divides $n$, what about $\frac{n}{d}$?

Comment: The relation is in the fact that every integer $n$ has a divisor $\leq\sqrt{n}$ and a divisor $\geq\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Probably adding [some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) would be useful. (Both close votes that have been cast so far cite "missing context" as the reason.) For example, what is $\sigma(n)$? Where does this problem come form?

Answer (score 4):

If $n=ab$, then one of $a,b$ is $\ge\sqrt n$